# Is DynamoDB a good choice for a Swift application?

Tags: swift, database, firebase, amazon-dynamodb, icloud

There is an assortment of DBs available. Have poked them all. What I need is one that's cost efficient, unique user ID, able to synch off line while no wifi. And access to the backend server records (items).

iCloud, Realm, mySQL, Firebase, DynamoDB, etc. I'm fairly solid in most, would love to use DynamoDB, but I'm seeing zero docs on synching, and wondering if it's that easy to have each user be assigned a unique ID, along with the associated AWS costs.

I'm settling in on iCloud or Firebase, wondering what the Swift pros think based on my needs.

thanks for tips. :-)

Comment: synch off line while no wifi?

Comment: Yes. Firebase seems to be good at that. It's a Smart Cities type app, you may be underground, offline, then pop out of a subway and now have wifi.

Comment: That is not really a feature of the database, that is the feature of the client that you use to connect to the database. It simply saves the data to disk until connection is once again available. This feature can be built for any database you mentioned.

Comment: Yes, can be built for sure, think that FB has done the building for you. Cutting out that development time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used a lot of Firebase and a bit of DynamoDB. Both are respectable choices.

I'll give you my biased view of why I chose Firebase over DynamoDB, and will let others give you the other angle:

- DynamoDB is great if all you want to do is put and get values based on keys. However, it is quite limited when it comes to querying and searching. Firebase excels in this, in terms of usability and speed. For example, if you have a database of users, you could query based on their child value (`lastLoggedIn`), and choose the users who just logged in today. If this query is done frequently, you could index on this key and speed up this query. Read more here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data
- Firebase allows you to define security rules for each table/database easily. You can define IAM roles in AWS for DynamoDB too, but I doubt they have as much flexibility as Firebase.
- Firebase allows for transactions that supports concurrent modifications: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions
- If you're developing a mobile app, push notifications are easy to set up.
- Offline capabilities are seamlessly integrated into your app without much setup: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities

I used to have doubts about Firebase, but ever since Google acquired Firebase in 2014, and talked about it so fervently in 2016 at Google I/O (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tb2GZ3Bh4p8&vl=en), I gained faith in it.

Oh, and did I say that the Blaze plan on Firebase is cheaper than DynamoDB for both storage and computation?

Comment: hi leonardloo,  thanks for the detailed writeup. Firebase it is. Have enough DynamoDB things working if needs come up, have another AWS/web project cooking. For this one, FB works great.  

Using this tutorial, the comments contains some fixes (with the pod file), else simple to setup and get and running.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/139322/firebase-tutorial-getting-started-2

Comment: I would do a comparison of both plans to find out which is cheaper in your case. DynamoDB has a  more generous free tier.